# Matrix equality in R

Tags: r, matrix

In R, the function `solve` can be used to solve matrix equations of form `A %*% x = b` for `x`.
I successfully performed `x <- solve(A,b)` with some valid set of linear equations, and went to check that my result was the correct answer.

I typed `A %*% x == b` and the result was

```
    [1]
[1] FALSE
[2] FALSE
...
[5] TRUE
```

but when I queried `A %*% x` the result was identical to `b`

Does this have to do with how I created the matrices?

```
A <- matrix(c(1,2, ... , 1), nrow=5, byrow = T)
b <- matrix(c(7,...,7), nrow=5)
```

The elipses are just because the numbers are irrelevant

Comment: Standard floating point error. Testing floats for equality is usually pointless. Try something like `abs(A %*% x - b) < 0.00001)`

Comment: You may try `all.equal()` instead